# Persisting self referencing entity not works

Tags: symfony

I create an entity with self referencing. My entity look like this:

```
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $parent;
}
```

And i create a form to edit a Question. With this form i can add many childs to a Question. After i post this form i will save the childs for a parent Object. But the persisting of childs for a parent fails, nothing happens in the database.

```
public function manageDependencyAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $question = $em->getRepository('AppMyBundle:Question')->find($id);

    if (!$question) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('objectNotFound'));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_question_list'));
    }

    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.question'), $question, array())->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'save', 'translation_domain' => 'messages', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        // dump($question->getChildren()); // This is not empty. In this array are the selected childs.

         $em->persist($question);
         $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: children is inverse side, but in doctrine auto persistence is only apply for owning side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your entity methods:

```
public function addChild(Question $children)
{
    $this->children[] = $children;
    $children->setParent($this);

    return $this;
}
```